# calling mvc function from razor html

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with MVC and i have question regarding calling function from my controller.

This is the function i want to call:

```
public ActionResult Index(string continent)
{
   try
   {
      return View(db.Factories.ToList());
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      string s = e.InnerException.Message;
   }

    return View( new FactoriesWController().GetFactoriesOnContinent(continent));
 }
```

I want to call this function from `cshtml` page, to be exact, this is drop down list.

I want to use selected item change to call the function and use selected item for function parameter. This is drop down list Razor code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Region", new SelectList(new List<string>() {"Europe", "Asia", "North America", "South America", "Africa", "Australia", "World"}),
                    "Select Region",new { @class = "form-control" })

<input type="submit" />
```

So i want to use selected item from drop down list and then call the function by using selected item as parameter. I never coded in HTML, any help appreciated.

Comment: you want to reload the page with the response from that action method ?

Comment: Change the name of the dropdownlist to match the parameter name - `@Html.DropDownList("continent", ...)` and wrap in a form with `FormMethod.Get` and submit the form or use ajax to post the selected value to the method if you want to stay on the same page and update the DOM

Comment: @Shyju yes exactly that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you please add some code example for the form? I deal with this stuff for the first time, thanks

Comment: Using ajax - `$('#Region').change(function() { $(someElement).load('@Url.Action("Index")', { continent: $(this).val() }) });` (but your method should be returning `PartialView()`, not `View()` If you want to redirect, then see Shyju's answer

Comment: With the current code, the SELECT element will not have `value` attribute for the options.It will have only `Text`.

Comment: @Shyju, `$(this).val()` will return the 'text' :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Are you sure ? http://jsbin.com/ziyipizasu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Shyju, - your alerting the `.val()` of the `<button>`, not the `<select>` :)

Comment: Yes. You are correct @StephenMuecke I did not know `val()` returns the text in the absence of a value. See this is the beauty of participating in SO. You learn some or the other thing every single day. Thank You.

Comment: @Shyju, And from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) _The value attribute provides a value for element. The value of an option element is the value of the value content attribute, if there is one, or, if there is not, the value of the element's text IDL attribute._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your form elements (SELECT and submit) inside a `form` tag. The `action` attribute of the form should point to your action method name. Rename your SELECT element name attribute value to match with your action method parameter name.

You can use the `Html.BeginForm` to generate the form tag.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "home"))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("continent",
        new SelectList(new List<string>() 
      {"Europe", "Asia", "North America", "South America", "Africa", "Australia", "World"}),
        "Select Region",
        new {@class = "form-control"})

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

*Assuming your `Index` action method is inside `HomeController`.*

Now when user selects an option from the SELECT element and click submit the selection will be submitted to the Index action method and selected option will be available in the `continent` parameter.

Comment: `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get)`

Comment: Post should also work(Even if the action method is GET action). Why  to specify Get ?

Comment: OP did not have `[HttpPost]` so assumed its a GET

Comment: Yes. But you can do a POST type form submit to a GET action

Comment: @Shyju Thank you for your answer it wokred! I am not able to vote up besouse my reputation is still under 15.

Comment: @PetarMijović, Don't worry, we are here :)